MongoDB missing from Apache Airflow Connections

MongoDB itself is installed on system with all dependencies, everything is uptodate as well. still not getting this.
Running Apache-Airflow on Docker.
Dags Files are also giving error of module not found, but in reality all modules are installed and updated.

Have you installed the corresponding provider https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mongo/stable/index.html?

Yes its installed and all requirments are also installed and upto date

May you attach your docker file or anything else related to verify it?
